# Homestead Site Returning "Service Unavailable"

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I previously used XAMPP to run web applications locally on a Windows 10 machine, but I am trying to transition to using Homestead.  I have an existing project written in Laravel 5.1 (yeah, that needs to be upgraded to a more current 8x framework, but that's not the issue right now). It was working fine in XAMPP, but I can't get the site to load locally using Homestead. I tried first using the standard nginx server, and kept getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. When I switched the server type to Apache (which I should be using anyway, as our staging and production environments use Apache), I get a "Service Unavailable" error instead.

I have read through several stack overflow questions with similar problems and tried to follow those solutions, but nothing is working.

Here is my **Homestead.yaml** file:

```
ip: "192.168.56.56"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\thisuser\Documents\Sites\mySite
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite

sites:
    - map: mysite.test
      to: /home/vagrant/mysite/public
      php: "7.1.33"
      type: "apache"

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
```

Snippet from my **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** file:
[image]

The relevant pat of the **/etc/hosts** file in my vagrant box (The IP was previously 127.0.0.1, but even after updating it and restarting Apache it still doesn't work):

```
### HOMESTEAD-SITES-BEGIN
192.168.56.56   mysite.test
### HOMESTEAD-SITES-END
```

My **.env file** (I have also regenerated the key and ran a composer install and composer dump-autoload):

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=LZKt8EK6iEeBt3Ec1ZIi2YePKMhdfNjT

#URL for making server-side rendered absolute links on some pages
APP_URL="http://mysite.test/"

#Determines whether to store sessions in file, in database, or using memcached
SESSION_DRIVER = 'database'
SESSION_ENCRYPT = true
```

The URL I am going to to view this site: http://mysite.test/.

In some stackoverflow answers, it was mentioned that PHP version 7.3 had an issue with xdebug. Even though I am using 7.1, I tried running `sudo phpdismod xdebug`, but that didn't have any visible effect.

I checked **storage/logs/laravel.log**, but nothing is being written to it. I checked the apache server logs, and don't see any errors. The php7-fpm log is completely missing from **/var/logs** (but there is a php8.1-fpm log).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please explain what I am missing, so that I can get this site running locally via Homestead? Thanks in advance for any assistance offered.

Comment: Your PHP FPM server logs should show you what the problem is. PHP 7 is end-of-life; PHP 7.1 hasn't been supported for years now. Same for Laravel 5. Running applications on these insecure platforms is bad practice.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I agree, it is an old stack. The project has been mostly re-written using Laravel 8.1 and PHP 8, but until it completes development and QA, we are running the old application in production, and that old application will need maintenance. 

I checked /var/logs but I don't see the php7.1-fpm.log; the only php fpm log available is for 8.1, even though I specified 7.1 in my yaml file and ran php71 in homestead.

Do you have any other advice or suggestions?

Comment: Well if PHP 8.1 is running, it will definitely not play nicely with Laravel 5 so that would be the source of your problem.

Comment: @miken32 It's odd, because when I go into my project folder and run php -v, it shoes me the proper version that I specified in the yaml file ( v7.1.33).

Comment: I have no experience with Homestead, I just have MySQL and Apache running on my laptop so I'm not of much help there I'm afraid ‍♂️ I would check your Apache config and make sure it's pointing to the correct socket or port for the FPM server.

Answer (score 1):

I attach an example of `.env` file.
[image: env file]

Also, I attach an example of `etc/hosts` file.
[image: hosts]

Please, take a look at the `Homestead.yaml` file and especially in folders block.
[image: homestead]

So, maybe there is a typo there:

```
- map: ~/mysite
  to: /home/vagrant/mysite
```

Finally, at sites section try to avoid adding any php:"" .

Comment: If you think this answer was helpful please mark it as accepted. Thanks!